# Approach of solving a probability question involving independent events not matching that given in my book.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question:**
A and B are two independent events. The probability that both A and B occur is $\frac{1}{6}$ and the probability that at least one of them occurs is $\frac{2}{3}$​. The probability of the occurrence of A= ___, given that P(A)=2P(B).

**My approach:**
Since it says the probability that **at least one** of them takes place is $\frac{2}{3},$

$$\sf{P(at\:least \:one \:occurs) \\\frac{2}{3}=1 - P(none\:occurs)\\\implies \frac{2}{3}=1-P(\overline{A} \cap \overline{B})\\ }$$ Now earlier in this book, it was told that for **independent events,** $P(X\cap Y) = P(X).P(Y)$ (always).
So continuing from above,
$$\implies \frac{2}{3}=1 - P(\overline{A})P(\overline{B}) \quad \cdots \bf{(1)}$$
And also,
$$\sf{P(both\:A\:and\:B\:occur)}=\frac{1}{6} \\ \implies \frac{1}{6} = P(A).P(B)\quad\cdots\bf{(2)}$$
Now solving for P(A) by making use of the fact $P(E) + P(\overline{E}) = 1$, I got $P(A) = \frac{1}{3} \: or \: \frac{1}{2},$ none of which matches the answer of the book.

**Approach given in the book:** $$P(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{6}, \: P(A \cup B) = \frac{2}{3}, \:P(A)=2P(B) \\ \\ P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) \\ \implies \frac{2}{3} = P(A) + \frac{1}{2}P(A) - \frac{1}{6} \\ \implies P(A) = \frac{5}{9} \\ \\$$
However, my doubt is, how does the book equate P(at least one event occurs) to $P(A\cup B)$, since $P(A\cup B)$ is the probability of occurrence of (either A or B)? When it is told at least one event, that should include {either A or B or (both A and B)} [which I think should be equal to 1 - P(none occurs).]

Comment: Your formula is good as well.  Indeed $P(A\cup B)=1-P((A\cup B)^c)=1-P(A^c\cap B^c)$.

Comment: Your problem is that you've assumed that $A$ and $B$ are independent, which they are not. The solution they've found actively contradicts that, because $P(A)=5/9$ and $P(B)=5/18$ would mean $1/6=P(A\cap B)=5/9\times 5/18=25/162$ which simply isn't true. I believe the word "independent" has been included into the problem statement by mistake.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop Ok that might be true. But even if the two events are not independent, shouldn't $$P(\sf{at \:least \:one \:occurs}) \\= 1-P(\sf{none\:occurs}) \\= 1-P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}) \neq P(A\cup B)?$$ While the book states:$$P(\sf{at\:least\:one\:occurs}) = P(\sf{A\cup B})$$

Comment: $\overline{\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}}=A\cup B$. This is known as De Morgan's law and you can convince yourself that it is true by drawing Venn diagrams.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop Thanks for the help :)